# how to visualise code dependencies for perl files?

Tags: perl, dependencies

With [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd409453.aspx), dependency graphs can be established. That's a rather cool feature.

My question focus on Perl --- Exists an adequate tool which could do that for Perl modules?

Comment: perhaps http://blogs.perl.org/users/neilb/2012/12/prereq-grapher.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you (just) want to show/find them [use ScanDeps](http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/Module-ScanDeps-1.11/lib/Module/ScanDeps.pm)

Via the command-line program scandeps.pl:

```
% scandeps.pl *.pm          # Print PREREQ_PM section for *.pm
% scandeps.pl -e "use utf8" # Read script from command line
% scandeps.pl -B *.pm       # Include core modules
% scandeps.pl -V *.pm       # Show autoload/shared/data files
```

Used in a program;

```
use Module::ScanDeps;

# standard usage
my $hash_ref = scan_deps(
    files   => [ 'a.pl', 'b.pl' ],
    recurse => 1,
);

# shorthand; assume recurse == 1
my $hash_ref = scan_deps( 'a.pl', 'b.pl' );

# App::Packer::Frontend compatible interface
# see App::Packer::Frontend for the structure returned by get_files
my $scan = Module::ScanDeps->new;
$scan->set_file( 'a.pl' );
$scan->set_options( add_modules => [ 'Test::More' ] );
$scan->calculate_info;
my $files = $scan->get_files;
```

if you want to display them in a nice graph/tree [use GraphViz2](http://search.cpan.org/~rsavage/GraphViz2-2.22/lib/GraphViz2.pm)

furthermore to scan CPAN dependencies you can give http://deps.cpantesters.org/ a try..

more options are:

[CPAN::FindDependencies](http://search.cpan.org/~dcantrell/CPAN-FindDependencies-2.42/lib/CPAN/FindDependencies.pm) - find dependencies for modules on the CPAN

```
use CPAN::FindDependencies;
my @dependencies = CPAN::FindDependencies::finddeps("CPAN");
foreach my $dep (@dependencies) {
    print ' ' x $dep->depth();
    print $dep->name().' ('.$dep->distribution().")\n";
}
```

[Module::Extract::Use](http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/Module-Extract-Use-1.03/lib/Module/Extract/Use.pm) - Pull out the modules a module uses

```
use Module::Extract::Use;

my $extor = Module::Extract::Use->new;

my @modules = $extor->get_modules( $file );
if( $extor->error ) { ... }

my $details = $extor->get_modules_with_details( $file );
foreach my $detail ( @$details ) {
    printf "%s %s imports %s\n",
    $detail->module, $detail->version,
    join ' ', @{ $detail->imports }
}
```

maybe [this conclusion](http://neilb.org/reviews/dependencies.html#conclusion) will light you up more..